# Will I have problems going to other countries after being refused entry to the UK?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

Sadly, I was refused to entry to UK at the border when I arrived at Heathrow. I wanted be there as a tourist 6 months, nothing else. Then, from London, I was planning to go to Nepal.

I had all my documents, but couldn't get the hostel booking, as it was full. I didn't think this would be an issue at the border. In the letter I was given by the officer, I was refused under Appendix V [of the immigration rules].

After the officer interviewed me, I was put in a room where I spent the night, before I was sent back to my home country, Chile.

I think this might mean that I am inadmissible to the UK. Will this issue make it more difficult to travel to other countries?

I love to travel, I love to know other cultures and to make a new friends, but with this I feel sad and insecure about my next travels.

Comment: I'm sorry you had to endure this. There isn't enough information in your post about why you were refused entry to the UK for us to comment or discuss; Appendix V is long, and contains many requirements and limits and rules, any one of which (or more) might have been applied to you. This refusal of entry to the UK should not affect your entry to any other country...although to enter any other country you must meet that country's immigration requirements.

Comment: This question should probably be moved to Travel.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the refusal letter with your personal details blanked out?

Answer (score 2):

I have been refused a UK Tourism visa with a refusal stamp on my passport, since then I have applied for Canadian, USA, and russian visas and got them all. I applied again for UK tourist visa and I have been refused again.
I guess this may impact your future UK Visa application but not so much the applications for other visas

Answer (score 1):

In general, other countries won't have the information that you were refused entry to the UK.  So the mere fact of your refusal won't be a problem.

What *may* be a problem is the reason you were refused entry.  If the same reason applies in future, other countries may wish to refuse you entry too.

---

**Edit:** I see there was a refusal stamp in your passport.  That could make things more difficult.  You may get asked about it; tell them you didn't realize you needed pre-booked accommodation.  Make sure that next time you *have* pre-booked (at least for the first few days). I would also suggest not planning a trip of six months (that is a *very* long tourist trip.  Also try going to places (in Africa for example?) that are less concerned about people trying to enter the country illegally.

Comment: Downvoter: What do you think I have wrong?

Comment: He could just get a new passport.

Comment: "I would also suggest not planning to go for six months" I first read this as "I suggest that you plan, for the next six months, on not going", and it was only on re-reading the OP that I interpreted it otherwise.

Comment: @Acccumulation Good point (particularly as this is most likely to be of interest to non-native speakers).  I have reword to avoid the confusion.

Comment: @victoriah You're basically advocating lying to all future immigration officials by trying to cover up the refusal.

Comment: "tell them you didn't realize you needed pre-booked accommodation": if the traveler received a written explanation of the reasons for refusal, keeping it with the passport would be a good idea.